# airflow.contrib.operators Module Import error

Tags: airflow

I am getting a module import error for "airflow.contrib.operators.sagemaker_training_operator" in airflow . I am using managed_worflow_apache_Airflow. How to rectify this

Airflow version=2.4.3

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models import XCom
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,timezone
from sqlalchemy import func
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json
import logging
import io
import os
import boto3
import uuid
import sagemaker
import time
from sagemaker.inputs import TrainingInput
from sagemaker.xgboost.estimator import XGBoost
from airflow.contrib.operators.sagemaker_training_operator import SageMakerTrainingOperator
```